# Chatbot Load time is Very Slow

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using Virtual assistant template to develop Chatbot.  To integrate the Chatbot inside my website, I am using Directline channel.
Whenever any user click on chatbot to chat, it take approximately 8-12 sec to show welcome message.
Can anyone help me on this so that chatbot will load fast.

App Service Plan Used: P1V2
Channel: DirectLine

Comment: ‘Allways on’ enabled in app-service settings?

Comment: Yes Its enabled

Comment: It might be because of this bug. Otherwise its better to share some code so people can look at that. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3431